# How to send and receive image as part of http form-data using requests and flask

Tags: opencv, http, flask, python-requests

I would like to make an http POST request, and include an image as part of the `multipart/form-data`. I'd like to avoid encoding this image as base64, and just send it as a binary blob, which I know that http can handle.

Here is my code on the client side:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
import json
import cv2


def post_encoded_image(url, headers):
    img = open("cyrus.jpg", 'rb').read()
    payload = {'image': img, 'identity': 'cyrus'}
    r = requests.post(url + "encoded-image", data=payload)
    print(r)

url = "http://localhost:8080/"
content_type = 'multipart/form-data'
headers = {'content-type': content_type}

post_encoded_image(url, headers)
```

On the server side, my code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import flask
import tfsdk
import numpy as np
from colorama import Fore
from colorama import Style
import os
import cv2

@app.route('/encoded-image', methods=['POST'])
def test():    
    image = request.form.get("image")
    nparr = np.fromstring(image, np.uint8)

    img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    print(type(img))

    return "success"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I make the request, the server prints the type of `img` as `NoneType`, meaning the call to `imdecode` didn't work, meaning something strange is going on the server side with the encoded image.

What is the proper way to do this?

**Edit**
I was able to achieve the desired functionality by doing the following:

client:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
import json
import cv2


def post_encoded_image(url, headers):
    img = open("cyrus.jpg", 'rb').read()
    file = {'image': img}
    data = {'identity': 'cyrus'}
    r = requests.post(url + "encoded-image", data=data, files=file)
    print(r)

url = "http://localhost:8080/"
content_type = 'multipart/form-data'
headers = {'content-type': content_type}

post_encoded_image(url, headers)
```

Server:

```
@app.route('/encoded-image', methods=['POST'])
def test():    
    ID = request.form.get("identity")
    image = request.files['image'].read()
    nparr = np.fromstring(image, np.uint8)
```

Is this the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired functionality as follows:

Client:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
import json
import cv2


def post_encoded_image(url, headers):
    img = open("cyrus.jpg", 'rb').read()
    file = {'image': img}
    data = {'identity': 'cyrus'}
    r = requests.post(url + "encoded-image", data=data, files=file)
    print(r)

url = "http://localhost:8080/"
content_type = 'multipart/form-data'
headers = {'content-type': content_type}

post_encoded_image(url, headers)
```

Server:

```
@app.route('/encoded-image', methods=['POST'])
def test():    
    ID = request.form.get("identity")
    image = request.files['image'].read()
    nparr = np.fromstring(image, np.uint8)
```